# how to run angular with ssl

Tags: angular, ssl

I try to run angular with ssl

here is an extract of angular.json

```
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "frontend:build",
        "sslKey": "keystore.p12",
        "sslCert": "myCertificate.crt",
        "ssl": true
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
        }
      }
    },
```

When I run ng serve, I have the following error message

```
Generating browser application bundles...An unhandled exception occurred: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
See "/private/var/folders/y7/g22dxgr12lvfsc1cn1q1v6_40000gn/T/ng-TNcET2/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Answer (score 0):

the key and certificate were not good. I found that if I apply the following code

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "frontend:build",
        "ssl": true
      },
```

and run ng serve, the key and certificate are automatically generated. In development mode, to make it run, I can generate the key and certificate files and install them on the local computer so the browser recognize them.

But How to add ssl facility in production mode

Comment: You shouldn't use the angular dev server for production. As the name implies, it is not tested for security. I heavily suggest using a dedicated server (e.g. nginx, express) for production deployment.

Comment: Hi Pascal, thank you for your answer. The main goal I try to reach is deploying a SpringBoot/Angular application in production. When I package the application which is formed of a SpringBoot module and an Angular module (https://marco.dev/deploy-java-angular-one), it produce a jar that I can java launch on a server. I added a ssl facility on the SpringBoot part, so that when I want to reach the application from a client, I do it hitting "https://   domain-name:8080."
I am wondering if I Have also to add ssl facility as I did above on the frontend module

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want your spring boot application to also serve your angular application? In that case, you would not use `ng serve` for your frontend application but rather `ng build - - prod` which only produces the static files but does not start the local dev server. Spring boot would then serve these static files, so there is no need for the frontend app to know about certs at all - spring boot handles that.

Comment: Thanks so much Pascal, that's exactly the answer I needed